# SQL Lab: How to fix procedural, function, package

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert the code below, but it won't run anything. I honestly don't have a lot of experience with SQL so I'm not exactly sure what to do. Basically we are trying to create a Bowler table and use the Bowler table as a foreign key. The code that is listed is for the score for each bowler

```
CREATE TABLE Score(
Game1 int(3),
G1Score1 int(3),
G1Score2 int(3),
G1Score3 int(3),
Game1Date date(9)

Game2 int(3),
G2Score1 int(3),
G2Score2 int(3),
G2Score3 int(3),
Game2Date date(9)


Game3 int(3),
G3Score1int(3),
G3Score2 int(3),
G3Score3 int(3),
Game3Date date(9)
BowelerId
CONSTRAINT ScorePK PRIMARY KEY (Score) 
CONSTRAINT BowlerIdFK FOREIGN KEY (BowlerId) );


INSERT INTO Score
    (BowlerId, Game1, G1Score1, G1Score2, G1Score3, Game1Date, Game2, G2Score1, G2Score2, G2Score3, Game2Date, Game3, G3Score1, G3Score2, G3Score3, Game3Date)
    VALUES ( '235462', 'Game 1', '210' '114', ‘150’, ‘01-APR-2019’, ‘Game 2’, ‘230’, ‘200’, ‘160’, ‘08-APR-2019’ ‘Game 3’, ‘100’, ‘120’, ‘150’, ‘16-APR-2019’) ;

INSERT INTO Score
(BowlerId, Game1, G1Score1, G1Score2, G1Score3, Game1Date, Game2, G2Score1, G2Score2, G2Score3, Game2Date, Game3, G3Score1, G3Score2, G3Score3, Game3Date)
    VALUES ('1234576''Game 1', '109', '149', ‘114’, ‘01-APR-2019’, ‘Game 2’, ‘180’, ‘210’, ‘240’, ‘08-APR-2019’, ‘Game 3’, ‘120’, ‘206’, ‘180’, ‘16-APR-2019’)

INSERT INTO Score
(BowlerId, Game1, G1Score1, G1Score2, G1Score3, Game1Date, Game2, G2Score1, G2Score2, G2Score3, Game2Date, Game3, G3Score1, G3Score2, G3Score3, Game3Date)
    VALUES ('768403','Game 1', '230', '200’, ‘150’, ‘01-APR-2019’, ‘Game 2’, ‘270’, ‘202’, ‘276’, ‘08-APR-2019’, ‘Game 3’, ‘164’, ‘210’, ‘150’‘, ‘16-APR-2019’)

INSERT INTO Score
(BowlerId, Game1, G1Score1, G1Score2, G1Score3, Game1Date, Game2, G2Score1, G2Score2, G2Score3, Game2Date, Game3, G3Score1, G3Score2, G3Score3, Game3Date)
    VALUES ('159635', 'Game 1', '109', '150', ‘150’, ‘01-APR-2019’, ‘Game 2’, ‘260’, ‘242’, ‘220’, ‘08-APR-2019’, ‘Game 3’, ‘109’, ‘180’, ‘150’, ‘16-APR-2019’)

INSERT INTO Score
(BowlerId, Game1, G1Score1, G1Score2, G1Score3, Game1Date, Game2, G2Score1, G2Score2, G2Score3, Game2Date, Game3, G3Score1, G3Score2, G3Score3, Game3Date)
    VALUES ('457910', 'Game 1', '200', '202', ‘180’, ‘01-APR-2019’, ‘Game 2’, ‘220’, ‘230’, ‘220’, ‘08-APR-2019’, ‘Game 3’, ‘109’, ‘180’, ‘260’,  ‘16-APR-2019’)




create table Bowler(
BowlerId    char(6) not null,
FirstName   varchar2(30) not null,
LastName    varchar2(30) not null,
PhoneNum    char(12),
Email       char(20) not null,
Status      char(15),
CONSTRAINT BowlerPK PRIMARY KEY (BowlerId) );

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    VALUES ( '235462', 'Faizan','Khan','417-555-5555', 'fkhan698@hotmail.com', 'Active');

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    VALUES ('1234576', 'John','Smith','417-666-6666', 'johnsmith@gmail.com', 'Active');

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    VALUES ('768403', 'Jane', 'Smith', '417-777-7777', 'janesmith@gmail.com', 'Active');

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    VALUES ('159635', 'Harry', 'Colbert', '573-616-3145', 'truesmith@gmail.com', 'Active');

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    VALUES ('457910', 'Frank', 'Reynolds', '417-953-7676', 'frank666@gmail.com', 'Active');

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    (VALUES (‘234839’, ‘Michael’, ‘Scott’, ‘573-268-3934’, ‘gdaddy@gmail.com’, ‘Inactive’);

INSERT INTO Bowler
    (BowlerId, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum, Email, Status)
    (VALUES (‘374837’, ‘Dwight’, ‘Schrute’, ‘418-392-3493’, ‘beets@gmail.com’, ‘Inactive’);
```

Comment: What does *it won't run anything* mean specifically? You've not described a problem yet.

Comment: It looks to me that the SQL you posted contains errors. For one, the foreign key constraint looks incorrect. Also I am unfamiliar with the data type `date(9)`. Is there such a data type in _Oracle_? If the SQL you posted is the actual SQL you tried to execute, then you should be getting errors. Perhaps you could post the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `CREATE TABLE` statement marked up and fixed as best as I can:

```
CREATE TABLE Score
 (ID_SCORE  NUMBER
    CONSTRAINT PK_SCORE
      PRIMARY KEY
      USING INDEX,

  BOWLERID  CHAR(6)
    NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT SCORE_FK1
      REFERENCES BOWLER(BOWLERID),

  Game1     int,   -- scale or precision are not allowed on the INT data type
  G1Score1  int,
  G1Score2  int,
  G1Score3  int,
  Game1Date date,  -- scale or precision are not allowed on the DATE data type

  Game2     int,
  G2Score1  int,
  G2Score2  int,
  G2Score3  int,
  Game2Date date,

  Game3     int,
  G3Score1  int,
  G3Score2  int,
  G3Score3  int,
  Game3Date date);
```

Your `INSERT` statements will fail because you're attempting to store strings (e.g. `'Game 1'`) in columns defined as `INT`, which means you can only store numbers in them. But once you get your table created you can proceed from there.

Best of luck.

### EDIT

I see there's a BOWLER table with BOWLERID as the primary key. I hadn't noticed that earlier. In that case it appears that what you wanted was to have a BOWLER_ID column on SCORE as a foreign key to BOWLER. I also added a SCORE_ID column to SCORE to serve as primary key.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hello. So I was able to create the `Score` table but I'm still having trouble with the `INSERT` statements. How do I implement the `BowlerId` onto the `Score` table like how I was trying to do on my first INSERT statments, because there needs to be a way to identify the Score of each person.